# How to wrap datatable around an image

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces, JSF 2. I would like to wrap datatable with text around an image. It is usually with normal text and float attribute but my text is inside a generated datatable. Is that some how possible? Or can you recommend me another solution?

Comment: @Thirumalai: please do not format non-code as code! Language/framework/API names like "PrimeFaces" and "JSF2" are not code!

Comment: OK, thank you for correction.